# Netbeans does not install on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: java, installation, netbeans

I have installed Big Sur on my MacBook Air. Java is installed but Netbeans install says no Java JDK found. Did anybody has the solution for this issue?

Comment: See user14808528 answer, you need NetBeans 12.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it by installing JDK15 and Apache Netbeans 12.2 (Only 12.2).

It works well.

Comment: This works on a Mac Mini (2020 M1) running Big Sur.  This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This works for me on Mac Pro 16inch Big Sur too. Actually this is the only answer I found that can help me out ( in an easiest way).

Comment: Working for MacOS Monterey also.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I resolved it. From the command line, I ran:

`/usr/libexec/java_home -V`

This will output the Java VMs you have installed:

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (4):
    14.0.1 (x86_64) "UNDEFINED" - "OpenJDK 14.0.1" /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/14.0.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.271.09 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java" /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_271 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_251 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_251.jdk/Contents/Home
```

If you don't see JDK 1.8, then you should go to [Oracle.com](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html) and install it. Assuming you have 1.8, you should set that as your `JAVA_HOME` with the following command:

`export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home"`

Note that your location may be slightly different from mine, you should use the location for 1.8 that was present in your list of VMs when you ran `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`, above. I would also recommend you add this to your shell profile so that the current JAVA_HOME is set the next time you reopen your shell. I'm using ZSH as my shell, so the command was:

`echo 'export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home"' >> ~/.zshrc`

Now you're almost home. Just make sure you have [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and then run `brew cask install netbeans`.

That should enable you to install it without issue and will place it in your Applications folder.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved my problem like this and it worked out wonderfully:

**Issue:**
When I executed Netbeans through command line in verbose mode, I saw the following error

*./netbeans -v

The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime that supports (null).
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.*

**Solution:**
Edit netbeans.conf file
*vi /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans\ 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/etc/netbeans.conf*
Look for netbeans_jdkhome variable, uncomment it and substitute it appropriately. In my case the setting was:
*netbeans_jdkhome="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home"*

Once you have done that, you can start Netbeans normally using the Netbeans shortcut or by using the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Same here , it is because Big Sur update have erased $JAVA_HOME. echo $JAVA_HOME is empty and you cannot redirect to .bash_profile . Maybe Big Sur updates will fix this. I am waiting/searching for an answer myself. Not about to downgrade to Catalina just yet

Comment: I could get Netbeans on Big Sur, but only after I have installed it on Catalina and copied the installed directory to Big Sur. It works now, but why not the install?