# Netbeans CAN't Install, Can't Find JDK on MacOS

Tags: java, macos, netbeans, java-8, operating-system

I'm trying to install NetBeans IDE 8.2 on macOS Big Sur 11.0.1, I have to use it because right now I'm doing a collaborative project as a final job delivery.

All my attempts failed, every time I try to install it appears "JDK not found".

I already have the JDK 8 and I've already done the configuration by the console.
when running this on the console: echo $JAVA_HOME or /usr/libexec/java_home -v
The JDK path appears:
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home

I would be very grateful for any help or idea!
Thanks

Comment: Already been answered. Please check the link below: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63424844/netbeans-does-not-install-on-macos-big-sor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63424844/netbeans-does-not-install-on-macos-big-sor)

Comment: that's what I meant I tried too and won't let me install the netbeans yet, expect an update?